# How can I get the __doc__ string of the calling function

Tags: python

Consider this function call

```
def f1():
    doc = 'how can I get the doc string of whoever calling me?'

def f2():
    '''Docstring'''
    f1()
```

f1 and f2 can be in different modules.

Is there any way `f1()` knows the doc string of whoever calling it? `f2()` in above example.

Comment: Are you saying `f1()` is called within `f2()`? And you want to find a dynamic way of getting `f2()`'s docstring?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion, I edited the question.

Comment: Marked as duplicate since I'm assuming you can figure out how to access `__doc__` on the caller

Comment: wow, I am surprise with that amount of code to address such simple requirement.

Comment: @AllanXu `doc = globals()[(inspect.stack()[1].function)].__doc__` gets exactly what you need. I don't think there is a huge need for all that code if you only want the docstring.